# Output degrees minutes from an OpenLayers coordinate, but without seconds?

Tags: javascript, html, openlayers, openlayers-3

The method `ol.coordinate.toStringHDMS()` will output in a format of degress, minutes and seconds with compass direction, e.g. `47° 59′ 59″ N 7° 50′ 59″ E`

But is there a way to output degrees and minutes without seconds? Truncating the seconds is not appropriate as it will ignore rounding.

e.g. the above example should round to `48° 00′ N 7° 51′ E` however truncating seconds would erronesouly give `47° 59′ N 7° 50′ E`

Comment: Why the down vote? At least give reason for why you think the question isn't "good"

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your own function derivating it from both

- [`ol.coordinate.toStringHDMS`](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/v4.6.5/src/ol/coordinate.js#L344)
- [`ol.coordinate.degreesToStringHDMS`](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/v4.6.5/src/ol/coordinate.js#L141) (the second one depends from the first function)

Answer (score 1):

Suggested derived functions:

```
function toStringHDM(coordinate) {
  if (coordinate) {
      return (degreesToStringHDM('NS', coordinate[1]) +
          ' ' +
          degreesToStringHDM('EW', coordinate[0]));
  }
  else {
      return '';
  }
}
```

and:

```
function degreesToStringHDM(hemispheres, degrees, opt_fractionDigits = 0) {
  var normalizedDegrees = modulo(degrees + 180, 360) - 180;
  var x = Math.abs(3600 * normalizedDegrees);
  var dflPrecision = opt_fractionDigits || 0;
  var precision = Math.pow(10, dflPrecision);
  var deg = Math.floor(x / 3600);
  var min = Math.floor((x - deg * 3600) / 60);
  var sec = x - deg * 3600 - min * 60;
  sec = Math.ceil(sec * precision) / precision;
  if (sec >= 60) {
      sec = 0;
      min += 1;
  }
  if (min >= 60) {
      min = 0;
      deg += 1;
  }
  return (deg +
      '\u00b0 ' +
      padNumber(min, 2) +
      '\u2032 ' +
      (normalizedDegrees == 0
          ? ''
          : ' ' + hemispheres.charAt(normalizedDegrees < 0 ? 1 : 0)));
}
```

Please note: assuming the compiler will do the job for me, I intentionally left a lot of dead code inside degreesToStringHDM() in order to keep it as close as possible to OpenLayers' original function degreesToStringHDMS(), should you need to compare both in the future (for example, when OpenLayers will be releasing a new version of this function, potentially fixing some bugs, you may be interested to perform a diff in order to quickly find  what needs to be fixed here...)